# How do I define a Func where it may be async

Tags: c#, async-await

I am writing a method where it will get a parameter like this:

```cs
ShowMessagePopupAsync(string header, string message, Func<string, Task> onClick, Func<Task>? onClose)
```

First off, `onClose` may be null hence the `?`.

But how should I declare the return value of the `Func`? It could be an async method where the code on the `OnClick` needs to use await and return a Task. Or it may be as simple as saving the passed string and setting a bool.

What should my parameter be to handle both of these?

```cs
public void OnClick(string message) {
    savedMessage = message;
}
    
public async Task<void> OnClick (string message) {
    var x = await SaveTheInfo (message);
    if (x > 3)
        await CallSomeone();
}
```

Comment: Both cases can be handled by declaring it to return `Task`. In case of synchronous execution you just return `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: _Types_ are awaitable, not _methods_. `async` is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first method to look like this:

```cs
public Task OnClick(string message) {
    savedMessage = message;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This first one doesn't have anything that needs to execute asynchronously, so you can just skip the `async` keyword and return `Task.CompletedTask`, which is useful for scenarios like this.

```cs
public async Task OnClick(string message) {
    var x = await SaveTheInfo(message);
    if (x > 3)
        await CallSomeone();
}
```

This second one can stay the way it is. You just don't need the `Task<void>` in the signature, because it's essentially the same as `Task`.

When two methods share the exact same signature, they cannot exist in the same class. In this case, both methods do share the same signature, the `async` keyword does **not** make a difference, because the compiler removes it.